# disable view when loading/saving data

Tags: angularjs

As it is now I am using [ngDisabled](https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification) to disable some buttons and some inputs after the user makes certain actions (like saving). But this makes a lot of clutter.

I am looking for a way to disable the current view, maybe have it 'phase out', or 'blur' somehow.

To show the user that the application is loading/saving data I am using [ui.notification](https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification). Would it be possible to 'focus' on this notification, so that the background is unclickable?

**Update**, showing one of my functions, where I use a notification.

```
$scope.deleteItem = function(ID){
    var result = confirm('You sure?');
    if (result) {

        // creating the notification
        var save = Notification.info({
            message: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i> Loading..',
            positionY: 'top',
            positionX: 'center',
            delay: false
        });

        var deleteItem = ItemService.removeItem(ID);
        deleteItem.then(function(){
            var elementPos = $scope.arrays.ItemArray.map(function(x) {return x.ID; }).indexOf(ID);
            $scope.arrays.itemArray.splice(elementPos,1);

            // when item is delted, delete notification
            save.then(function(notification){
                notification.kill(true);
            });

            $scope.fetchData();
        },function (reason) {
            console.log(reason);

            // if item is not deleted (error) show error notice
            Notification.error({
                message: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Error',
                positionY: 'top',
                positionX: 'center',
                delay: 2000
            });
            // delete 'loading' notification
            save.then(function(notification){
                notification.kill(true);
            });

        });
    }
};
```

Comment: You can display a modal with a message and close it when the request promise get resolved or rejected

Comment: @Raulucco I did this for a while, pretty much the same issue I have now, can't seem to keep it 'clean' enough. With `ui.notification` it's very nice so far, except for this issue

Comment: Try adding `tabindex="0"` to your notification template root element or higher value. But i am skeptic that this will help. Usually the best option will be to listen for a shown event or a promise resolution, but i don't see that possibility whit the ui.notification service.

Comment: @Raulucco like so: `<div class="ui-notification" tabindex="0">` ? This did not work :/

Comment: Yep I thought so that this would be enough. But without the service providing any promise or so I can't tell how to do it ... This is because I thought of wrapping the bootstrap modal into a service of your own and set manually the focus on the element. If the issue is with accessibility try to setup a attribute `role="alertdialog"` to the template.

Comment: Why not ngCloak or ngIf on the view?

Comment: @JohannesJander I don't want to hide anything, just phase it out, focus the notification, or simple make it disabled, without using ng-disable. I wan't higher priority on my notification popup

Comment: @Raulucco can you take a look at the function I provided in the update, anything that could be done there?

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to go for the suggestion from @Raulucco , using a modal

In order for the modal to know when the loading/saving is done I had to create a factory, so far it looks like this:

```
myApp.factory('info', function() {
    return {
        status: '',
        info: ''
    }
});
```

Inject my info factory into my controller

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $log, $uibModal, info ) {

$scope.info = info;
```

And the modal function looks like this

```
$scope.showInfo = function() {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'infoModal.html',
        controller: 'infoCtrl',
        size: 'sm',
        animation: 'true',
        backdrop: 'static',
        resolve: {
            info: function() {
                return $scope.info;
            }
        }
    });
    modalInstance.result.then(function (editable) {

    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
};
```

With controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('infoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, info) {

$scope.icon = 'fa fa-spinner fa-pulse';
$scope.color = 'blue';
$scope.editable = info;

$scope.$watch('editable.status', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue == 'success'){
        $scope.icon = 'fa fa-check';
        $scope.color = 'green';
        $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
    } else if (newValue == 'error') {
        $scope.icon = 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle';
        $scope.color = 'red';
    }
});
$scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
};
});
```

To open modal, just call it when you need it

```
    $scope.info.info = '';
    $scope.info.status = 'loading..';
    $scope.showInfo();
```

And to close modal, change `$scope.info.status` when loading/save is done

```
$scope.info.status = 'success';
```

The `$watch` in modal controller keeps track of the status, and closes if it is 'success'

This may look complicated, but it turned out okay. The only thing I am afraid of is the use of `$watch`, but it seems ok